# What's different from jettyrunner and full jetty distribution

Tags: jetty

What's the different between jettyrunner and a full jetty distribution?

Is jettyrunner lack of something?

If so, can I add some jar (like jetty-websocket.jar) to classpath instead of using full distribution folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jetty-runner artifact is a way to start up some (most?) web applications directly from the commandline.  To do this it works around some of the normal conventions related to webapp classloaders, etc but it is really a fairly limited feature set at this point, we haven't see the groundswell of response to it needing features like websocket support at this point so haven't really even looked at what would be required to do that.

The full jetty distribution is increasing becoming a solid path forward for the more operations focused lot as well, with nice new features for HOME and BASE directories, as well as allowing for tiers of BASE directory configuration letting you share common configurations or libraries across multiple distinct application bases, etc... if that all sounds greek, it should make sense to the normal corporate operations type person :)

Comment: So ... no alternative then for a programmatic Jetty start? ... what a pitty ... obviously you can use a full Jetty distribution but we are talking about a Maven, Gradle or SBT local development on the fly start ... it's painful when people deprecates stuff without alternatives ... I think they should call it KILLING instead of deprecating ... that at least will be more realistic, painful but realistic